# How to reduce width of container to children width when "left:0" and "right:0" are used?

Tags: html, css

Currently, the container is stretched out to `max-width`, which is `520px`. I notice this happens when I applied `left:0` and `right:0`. Reason I used those properties is I would like to bottom center the element(pink container).

The width of child content including padding is `206px`, but since `min-width` is `240px`, I would like the width of the pink container to be `240px` wide, but pink container is still at `520px`. It does not shrink with child content, it just stays at `max-width`.

How can I make adjustment so that width of pink container adjust according to width of child content? So if child content is `300px`, I would like pink container to be `300px` wide.

```css
.parentContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 520px;
  min-width: 240px;
  background-color: pink;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.childContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.contentContainer {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="childContainer">
    <div class="contentContainer">
      <h4>Hellow World!</h4>
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to adjust the parent width according to the child width, you can use `width: fit-content` for the parent.

Try this code out:

```
.parentContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  min-width: 240px;
  background-color: pink;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```